# ERROR 2343 Specified Path Is Empty

Tags: windows-7, pro-tools

I have been getting this error all day while trying to install Avid ProTools 11HD.

I Have to install it on 12 Workstations, so far, 6 of the workstations have it installed without any issues, 4 workstations keep giving me the above error when trying to install.

I have used Microsoft FixIT tool and that didn't help.

I have cross referenced what a working machine and non working machine had on them, removed/installed programs to make them the same, still got the error.

I extracted the download with 7zip, winrar
Created a new user account locally and on the domain

I Uninstalled nvidia drivers, .net framework

Actually used windows update to see if that worked but nothing.

In the installation Log this is the only error i can find which has not helped me much.

> MSI (c) (C8:44) [15:27:13:769]: Disallowing installation of component: {997FA962-E067-11D1-9396-00A0C90F27F9} since the same component with higher versioned keyfile exists
>
> MSI (c) (C8:44) [15:27:13:769]: Disallowing installation of component: {474F61F1-7342-11D2-A199-00A0C90AB50F} since the same component with higher versioned keyfile exists
>
> MSI (c) (C8:44) [15:27:13:779]: Disallowing installation of component: {10048713-2C96-11D2-9A97-006097C4E452} since the same component with higher versioned keyfile exists
>
> MSI (c) (C8:44) [15:27:13:779]: Disallowing installation of component: {CEBE74C7-D324-35F7-BDE1-EE49F5BDDCA8} since the same component with higher versioned keyfile exists
>
> MSI (c) (C8:44) [15:27:13:779]: Disallowing installation of component: {F998CD58-D7C7-3490-82A7-10C077E01575} since the same component with higher versioned keyfile exists
>
> MSI (c) (C8:44) [15:27:13:779]: Disallowing installation of component: {2249D6D1-5178-3455-89F6-D9A68A8A988D} since the same component with higher versioned keyfile exists
>
> MSI (c) (C8:44) [15:27:13:779]: Disallowing installation of component: {E8D55BCE-DA54-3E98-BABD-10607DA0E634} since the same component with higher versioned keyfile exists
>
> MSI (c) (C8:44) [15:27:13:779]: Disallowing installation of component: {AD19AE30-281F-3251-AA0A-55E6377ED3F5} since the same component with higher versioned keyfile exists
>
> MSI (c) (C8:44) [15:27:13:779]: Disallowing installation of component: {0E931026-929B-382C-B702-B8B4039399E5} since the same component with higher versioned keyfile exists
>
> MSI (c) (C8:44) [15:27:13:779]: skipping installation of assembly component: {68B7C6D9-1DF2-54C1-A01F-C8B3B9A1E18E} since the assembly already exists
>   MSI (c) (C8:44) [15:27:13:779]: skipping installation of assembly component: {63E949F6-03BC-5C40-A01F-C8B3B9A1E18E} since the assembly already exists
>   Action ended 15:27:13: CostFinalize. Return value 1.
>
> MSI (c) (C8:44) [15:27:13:789]: Skipping action: SetAVXLOCATION_Install.B3BD9DBC_D31A_4669_BAC7_78FAFFB6EBD8 (condition is false)
>
> MSI (c) (C8:44) [15:27:13:789]: Doing action: SetCOMMONDOCUMENTS.B3BD9DBC_D31A_4669_BAC7_78FAFFB6EBD8
>   Action 15:27:13: SetCOMMONDOCUMENTS.B3BD9DBC_D31A_4669_BAC7_78FAFFB6EBD8. 
>   Action start 15:27:13: SetCOMMONDOCUMENTS.B3BD9DBC_D31A_4669_BAC7_78FAFFB6EBD8.
>
> MSI (c) (C8:44) [15:27:13:789]: Note: 1: 2343 
>   Error 2343.Specified path is empty.
>
> MSI (c) (C8:44) [15:28:40:990]: Product: Avid Pro Tools -- Error 2343.Specified path is empty.

Edit: The 12 machines are all the same make/model, all running windows 7 pro 64-bit, and Avid ProTools has not been installed on it before.

Looking through the Avid forums there were 2 posts regarding this error, one solution was to use winrar, and the other was to extract the programs in the C directory, neither worked for me.

Has anyone experienced this issue before? need it resolved for Monday and i cannot find anything new online regarding it.

Comment: No and there isn't any anti-virus stalled on the pc as it's a fresh install of windows.

Answer (score 0):

All of the errors you've pasted, are related, in suite, to this problem.  For whatever reason, you've got conflicting entries in your registry, and must delete them.  You may also need to search and remove all traces of anything from Avid, Digidesign, or Air, on your computer.

You could also confirm that you have completely downloaded this installer file (e.g. do a checksum on the installer files vs the working install machines intstaller file), and make sure the file was not corrupted, etc.  This probably has resulted, as well, in things on your computer you need to erase  **either way.**

See [this article](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ADP1Lcqhx0sJ:www.symantec.com/connect/ideas/how-fix-error-2343-specified-path-empty-when-upgrading-without-using-microsoft-cleanup-utility+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=de) for an example of how to clean the crap out of your registry.

If you are unable to open Windows "device manager" without getting the same error, it means that you have corrupted drives (in this case sound or video), and probably have a virus issue on your machine.  In this case you need a Fresh Windows install, unless there is an enterprise level virus-solution that really fixes all the problems [this is personally out of my realm].  There are multiple posts from Windows Support online about the same issue.

Try doing a fresh Windows install on one of the Machines, if absolutely necessary.  Windows users should be used to this type of thing, right :Ö)

Have you installed Quick Time already?

Did you know that Quick Time (needed for Pro Tools mp3 and video support on Windows) is not supported anymore by Apple?  There are at least 2 critical security issues already known, that will never be fixed.

So because of this I would also recommend that until Avid has a work around, to not connect those computers to the Internet, other than when absolutely necessary.

Comment: 1/ Why are you linking to a google cache entry when the non-cached link works? 2/ What has QuickTime got to do with this question? 3/ What has "device" manager go to do with this question? 4/ Why do you think the OP has a virus?